# DropDownList datasource + empty value

Tags: asp.net

i have a DropDownList which is getting data from dataset,
the dropdownlist show all the data from the dataset perfect,
but i want to add an empty value to the list as the default selected value.
how do i do it ?

Comment: Depends what your datasource object is. What are you using as the datasource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
ActionsMenu.DataSource = myDataSource;
ActionsMenu.DataTextField = "value";
ActionsMenu.DataValueField = "key";
ActionsMenu.DataBind();

// after the binding
ActionsMenu.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select an action...", String.Empty));
ActionsMenu.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("-------------------", String.Empty));
```

d.

Comment: Hi Dibier, can you help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227570/dropdownlist-inside-edititemtemplate

Answer (score 2):

After you Bind the list, you could make use of Insert.

Example:

```
LISTNAME.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Text", "Value") );
```

The 0 is telling it to go in the first spot of the List.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
dropdownlist.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(0, "< Select an option >"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your options are:

1. Add it to you datatable
2. Add it after the databinding event in the page lifecycle has completed.
3. Add it on the client using javascript or jquery.