# DropDownList inside EditItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a dropdown within an EditTemplate as such:

```
    <EditItemTemplate>                      
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBusinessType" runat="server"  DataSourceID="BusinessTypeSource"  DataTextField="Value" DataValueField="Value" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Text='<%# Bind("BusinessType") %>'>
           <asp:ListItem>Please Select</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>                                                         
    </EditItemTemplate>
```

The DataSource has the following value:

```
Personal
Professional
```

The problem that I am running into is that the field that I am binding has a blank value.
As a blank value is not in the DataSource I get the following error message:

*'ddlBusinessType' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value*

Not sure how to fix this. When I do my binding, if the value is not in the datasource, I like to default it to 'Please Select'

Comment: You are trying to select the value before the Bind process. You should move this behavior to DataBound event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the circumstances, but one option I'll use often times is as follows:

1) In the lookup table, I'll have an entry titled 'Not Selected',
    with a primary key value of 0 (or whatever).

2) In the transaction table, update all of the null values for that field to 0 (or whatever the value is for your 'Not Selected' option).  Also, set the default value of that field to 0.

This is nice for a couple of reasons -- one, no special mark-up required (so you know it will always be consistent) -- and two, wherever *else* you use this data, you'll have access to the 'not selected' output.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like:

```
<EditItemTemplate>                      
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBusinessType" runat="server"  
        DataSourceID="BusinessTypeSource"  
        DataTextField="BusinessType" DataValueField="Value" AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
        <asp:ListItem  Value="-1">Please Select</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>                                                         
</EditItemTemplate>
```

1) No need to set Text as you already bounded the text field.

2) You need to set a value for default item you have added in markup.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select an item before binding process. Capture Binding event and set de selected value on this place.